# See Values Passed To Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

For our production server we do not actually copy over the Visual Studio .sln file so I can't "launch" the site for debugging from our production server.  In a totally different application I am launching an .aspx page and attempting to pass variables from the source program to my .aspx page.  W/O the .sln file from Visual Studio being copied over how can I debug and step through my syntax to see if the variables are actually being passed?

Answer (score 1):

It's a *production* environment. No development and/or debugging tools shoud *ever* be installed into a production environment.

What you want to do is:

1. *Test* your code properly.
2. Add [*logging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logfile).
3. In case of an issue encountered in the production environment, inspect log files.